# how to update inbox after receiving sms from broadcastReceiver? android

Tags: android

I am creating an SMS app, I am stuck in sms receiver,
Here is my sms receiver codes

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
    if (intentExtras != null) {
        Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
        String smsMessageStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

            String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

            smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
            smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine making good toast, but it doesnt update inbox, how to update inbox? ( context://inbox)

Comment: just cant understand your question...are you using your own messaging app or what?

Comment: yes, I am creating my own messaging app

Comment: ok....then you have to manage a list...you have to append new message to that list each time

Comment: I get list from "content://sms/inbox" so, I want to update it, so it automatically gets from it.. If i append only in my list then will other app be able to get the new message?

Comment: @mjt, Yes, assuming that's what you want. There are more things you need to do if you don't want the other apps to update their messages with the new one.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, when sms is received, my app is only able to show toast but not able store as inbox, if its stored on some db then only my app can get that message, what i want is to update default inbox of phone so all messaging app can read it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I solved it, here is how its done, hope it helps someone

adding of contentValues and passing it via context.getContentResolver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
    if (intentExtras != null) {
        Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String smsMessageStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

            String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

            smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
            smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";

            /*creating the content values to pass to inbox*/
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address",address);
            values.put("body",smsBody);

            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
           //contentResolver.insert(uriSMSURI, values);

            /*push to inbo*/
            context.getContentResolver().insert(uriSMSURI,values);

        }
        Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I was also expecting that inbox would be updated automatically, without manual content resolver invocation. So weird it isn't documented anywhere!

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, you totally rock, this solved a big issue I had. Thanks for coming back with the solution. I searched all over the internet with the words "save" "saving" SMS into Content Resolver, never found a clue about it, then I realized it was the Insert method that did the trick with what you posted

Answer (score -1):

add a receiver in your inbox Activity

```
class UpdateInboxBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateInbox(); // custom implementation for updating inbox adapter
    }

}
```

then in your receiver send broadcast to your inbox activty

```
public void sendBroadcast(String message){

    Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent();
    broadCastIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    broadCastIntent.setAction("updateInbox");
    this.sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
    stopSelf();
}

public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
if (intentExtras != null) {
    Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
    String smsMessageStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])    sms[i]);

        String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
        String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

        smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
        smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
sendBroadcast(smsMessageStr);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer a question.